# Calculate an integral that has a sum within.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Im trying to calculate this integral: $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n \sin(nx)}{2^n}$

The only thing I have been able to do is switch the integral and the sum, and in the end say that its converting. If I go about calculating I get this: 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{n \sin(nx)}{2^n} =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}   \frac{n}{2^n} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(nx)  =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{2^n} ((-1)^n-1 )$$

What should I do next? Or is this good enough?

Comment: Do you know how to sum Arithmetico-geometric series?

Comment: No im afraid I dont, I dont remember reading about it in my real analysis book.

Comment: From integrating $\sin (nx)$, you get a factor $\frac{1}{n}$, not $n$. So you get $n^{1-1}$ and not $n^{1+1}$ in the sum. That makes it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac n{2^n}\int\limits_9^\pi\sin nx\;dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac n{2^n}\left.\left(-\frac1n\cos nx\right)\right|_0^\pi=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n-1}{2^n}=$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2^n}-\sum_{n+1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}=\frac{\frac12}{1-\frac12}-\frac{-\frac12}{1+\frac12}=1+\frac13=\frac43$$

Comment: Thank you! I see that I made a mistake at the integration, I will write it down perfect now :D

Comment: Way to go, @Rabea

Answer (score 2):

Notice that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^n}\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin (nx) dx =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^n} \Big[\frac{-\cos (nx)}{n}\Big]_{0}^{\pi} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \Big[1-(-1)^n\Big] $$

Can you take from here?  You can use the sum of geometric series.

Comment: Yeah thank you! I see what I did wrong and how to work it out now.

Comment: Glad I could help.